# Can text be inserted into a fusion chart?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, graph, fusioncharts

I'm using the Grid component in fusion charts and need a date string to be used in the value place. It will always fail when i do this as it is looking for a number. Is there anyway it can allow text to be used aswell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ability to have date-time axis values is not yet available in FusionCharts. Nevertheless, the use case for you does not fit right.

Ideally, the grid component's right column should show a number (value). The left column is text showing the labels. For a grid, it makes very less sense to have text on both columns.

Instead of a date, the right column should show how many month's or days or hours, etc.

---

Excerpts from FusionCharts documentation: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/advanced/number-format/Number_Scaling.html

Say we're plotting a chart which indicates the time taken by a list of automated processes. Each process in the list can take time ranging from a few seconds to few days. And we've the data for each process in seconds itself. Now, if we were to show all the data on the chart in seconds only, it won't appear too legible. What we can do is build a scale indicating time and then specify it to the chart. This scale, in human terms, would look something as under:

60 seconds = 1 minute
60 minute = 1 hr
24 hrs = 1 day
7 days = 1 week

Now, to convert this scale into FusionCharts XML format, you'll have to do it as under:

1. First you would need to define the unit of the data which you're providing. Like, in this example, you're providing all data in seconds. So, default number scale would be represented in seconds. We can represent it as `<chart defaultNumberScale='s' ...>`
2. Next, we define our own scale for the chart as: `<chart numberScaleValue='60,60,24,7' numberScaleUnit='min,hr,day,wk' >`. If you carefully see this and match it with our range, you'll find that whatever numeric figures are present on the left hand side of the range is put in numberScaleValue and whatever units are present on the right side of the scale has been put under numberScaleUnit - all separated by commas.
3. Set the chart formatting flags to on as: `<chart formatNumber='1' formatNumberScale='1' ...>`

The entire XML would look like:

```
<chart defaultNumberScale='s' numberScaleValue='60,60,24,7' numberScaleUnit='min,hr,day,wk'><set label='A' value='38' /><set label='B' value='150' /><set label='C' value='11050' /><set label='D' value='334345' /><set label='E' value='1334345' /></chart>
```

A sample grid (not with the above data) would look like this:[image: SS grid with numberscaleunit]